# Digital I/O controls

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm brand new to coding and Arduino. I'm trying to learn mostly just for fun. I've got an ok grasp on the very basic I would like to think. I'm now trying something for a project and I can't quite get it to work how I want. I'm trying to use two digital input signals comparied to control two digital  outputs.

here is what I'm trying to work out:

if inputA=HIGH and inputB=HIGH
then outputA=HIGH and outputB=LOW

if inputA=HIGH and inputB=LOW
then outputA=HIGH and outputB=HIGH

if inputA=LOW and inputB=High
then outputA=LOW and outputB=LOW

if inputA=LOW and inputB=LOW
then outputA=LOW and outputB=LOW

Here is my first code I tried that did not work:

```
const int inputA = 1;
const int inputB = 2;
const int outputA = 12;
const int outputB = 13;

int inputAstate = 0;
int inputBstate = 0;

void setup()
{
pinMode (inputA, INPUT);
pinMode (inputB, INPUT);
pinMode (outputA, OUTPUT);
pinMode (outputB, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  {inputAstate = digitalRead(inputA);
   inputBstate = digitalRead(inputB);
    {
    if(inputAstate == HIGH && inputBstate == HIGH)

    digitalWrite(outputA, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(outputB, LOW);
    }
    {
    if (inputAstate == HIGH && inputBstate == LOW)

    digitalWrite(outputA, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(outputB, HIGH);
    }
    {
    if (inputAstate == LOW && inputBstate == LOW)

    digitalWrite(outputA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(outputB, LOW);
    }
    {
    if (inputAstate == LOW && inputBstate == HIGH)

    digitalWrite(outputA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(outputB, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be sprinkling curly braces around your program randomly. Learn the language -- this is a really basic syntax issue.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Like said I'm still learning. I will admit that one thing I know I need help on is exactly what you pointed out. Learning what needs to be inside of what {}() and where. I've worked with the basic example codes that come with the Arduino soft wear up until now. This is my first try at a code of my own from scratch. Any further information on which {} that may needed to be taken out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aside: logically, your code could be simplified. `outputA <- inputA; outputB <- inputA & !inputB;`

Comment: cHao learning how to simplify this and have the end efect be the same would be great but the exaple you provided here doesn't look like anything I've even looked into learning yet.

Comment: That's because it's not C++. It's pseudocode. Look through all the possible states (there being only 4), and you see that pin `outputA` is always and only high if pin `inputA` is, and pin `outputB` is high only if pin `inputA` is high and pin `inputB` isn't.

Comment: Ok, I follow your explanations of the possible states and, after reading your explanation and looking back at your example I believe I understand it. However how can I use that in relation to writing a program for an Arduino?

Comment: You only need 3 if statements. First check if A is high, then check B. In the `else` part of the first `if`, you already know A is low, so the final `if` checks B.

Comment: Can a (properly configured) digital input be something besides `HIGH` or `LOW`? Cause if not, then you can do this with a single `if` and `else`.

Comment: If you do not define a state from what I understand the pin will float. That won't work for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment you are basically missing the point of curly braces. But since you mentioned you are new to all of this:
A conditional can be written the following way and the curly braces cover the scope for it. (Infact they cover scope anywhere else too).

```
if (something)
{
    Do some other thing.
    Do some thing else.
}
Do this anyways.
```

And by modifying your code with this logic, you should be able to fix your issues.

Comment: ok so from what you said it sounds like I need to take { from before the if  and place it at the end of that line so that only the digitalWrites are inside.

Comment: Yes, that would solve your problem. But you are still using unnecessary braces in the loop() function. You just need one starting and end brace to scope the function declaration :)

Comment: I believe I know which set you are talking about. Once this two for two is working I intend to duplicate it only using inputC and inputD with outputC and outputD. By placing the input#State=digitalRead inside a set that links it to those four if statments right. Hopefully that makes since.